# Como ver conteudo de um arquivo .bin gerado em c

Tags: c, binary, dev-c++

Tive que criar um programa em C que lê um arquivo(.txt) de ativação de sensores de movimentos e produz um arquivo binário com as mesmas informações.

O arquivo .txt tem as seguintes informações:

```
   3B2 20051023 014857393 609f
   3B3 20051023 014857393 00ff
   3B4 20051023 014857503 609f
   3B5 20051023 014857503 00ff
   3B6 20051023 014857613 6093
   3B7 20051023 014857613 807f
   3B8 20051023 014857723 609f
   3B9 20051023 014857723 00ff
   3BA 20051023 014857834 609f
   3BB 20051023 014857864 00ff
   3BC 20051023 014904113 807f
   3BD 20051023 014904113 08f7
   3BE 20051023 014904223 807f
   3BF 20051023 014904223 00f7
```

Criei o seguinte código em C para ler o arquivo e salva-lo dentro de um novo arquivo .bin, minha duvida esta em como abrir esse arquivo .bin e conferir se o que esta gravado esta correto, exite algum programa que converta arquivo .bin para .txt?

Código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int  data1,hora1;
    char sequencial1[4],ativacao1[5],nomeEntrada[50],nomeSaida[50];
    FILE *arqEntrada, *arqSaida;

    printf("Digite 2 nomes de arquivo: ");
    scanf("%s %s",&nomeEntrada,&nomeSaida);

    if ((arqEntrada = fopen(nomeEntrada,"r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Problema na abertura do arquivo %s.\n",nomeEntrada);
        return -1;      
    }
    if ((arqSaida = fopen(nomeSaida,"wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Problema na abertura do arquivo %s.\n",nomeSaida);
        return -1;      
    }
    while (fscanf(arqEntrada,"%s %d %d %s",&sequencial1, &data1, &hora1, &ativacao1) > 0) {
            fwrite(&sequencial1,sizeof(char),3,arqSaida);
            fwrite(&data1,sizeof(int),1,arqSaida);
            fwrite(&hora1,sizeof(int),1,arqSaida);
            fwrite(&ativacao1,sizeof(char),4,arqSaida);
    } 

    fclose(arqEntrada);
    fclose(arqSaida);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Windows ou Linux?

Comment: Estou usando o windows.

Comment: [Aqui](http://www.winhex.com/winhex/) tem um editor/visualizador de arquivos binarios para Windows.

Comment: Ou [este](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) que eu pessoalmente já usei

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conversor:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_BUF_LEN 100

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    FILE * fin = NULL;
    FILE * fout = NULL;
    char buf[ MAX_BUF_LEN ] = {0};
    int nlinha = 1;
    int n = 0;
    int seq = 0;
    int ativ = 0;
    int dt = 0L;
    int hr = 0L;

    if(argc < 3)
    {
        printf( "Erro de Sintaxe:\n\t%s entrada.txt saida.bin\n", argv[0] );
        return 1;
    }

    if((fin = fopen( argv[1] , "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Erro abrindo arquivo para leitura: %s\n", argv[1] );
        return 1;
    }

    if((fout = fopen(argv[2], "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf( "Erro abrindo arquivo para gravacao: %s\n", argv[2] );
        fclose(fin);
        return 1;
    }

    while( fgets( buf, MAX_BUF_LEN, fin) )
    {

        if((n = sscanf( buf, "%X %d %d %x", &seq, &dt, &hr, &ativ )) != 4)
        {
            printf( "Erro de leitura: %s:%d\n", argv[1], nlinha );
            continue;
        }

        fwrite( &seq, sizeof(short), 1, fout );
        fwrite( &dt, sizeof(int), 1, fout );
        fwrite( &hr, sizeof(int), 1, fout );
        fwrite( &ativ, sizeof(short), 1, fout );

        nlinha++;
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);

    return 0;
}
```

Entrada:

```
   3B2 20051023 014857393 609f
   3B3 20051023 014857393 00ff
   3B4 20051023 014857503 609f
   3B5 20051023 014857503 00ff
   3B6 20051023 014857613 6093
   3B7 20051023 014857613 807f
   3B8 20051023 014857723 609f
   3B9 20051023 014857723 00ff
   3BA 20051023 014857834 609f
   3BB 20051023 014857864 00ff
   3BC 20051023 014904113 807f
   3BD 20051023 014904113 08f7
   3BE 20051023 014904223 807f
   3BF 20051023 014904223 00f7
```

Saída:

```
$ xxd -g1 -c12 teste.bin 
0000000: b2 03 4f f4 31 01 b1 b4 e2 00 9f 60  ..O.1......`
000000c: b3 03 4f f4 31 01 b1 b4 e2 00 ff 00  ..O.1.......
0000018: b4 03 4f f4 31 01 1f b5 e2 00 9f 60  ..O.1......`
0000024: b5 03 4f f4 31 01 1f b5 e2 00 ff 00  ..O.1.......
0000030: b6 03 4f f4 31 01 8d b5 e2 00 93 60  ..O.1......`
000003c: b7 03 4f f4 31 01 8d b5 e2 00 7f 80  ..O.1.......
0000048: b8 03 4f f4 31 01 fb b5 e2 00 9f 60  ..O.1......`
0000054: b9 03 4f f4 31 01 fb b5 e2 00 ff 00  ..O.1.......
0000060: ba 03 4f f4 31 01 6a b6 e2 00 9f 60  ..O.1.j....`
000006c: bb 03 4f f4 31 01 88 b6 e2 00 ff 00  ..O.1.......
0000078: bc 03 4f f4 31 01 31 6b e3 00 7f 80  ..O.1.1k....
0000084: bd 03 4f f4 31 01 31 6b e3 00 f7 08  ..O.1.1k....
0000090: be 03 4f f4 31 01 9f 6b e3 00 7f 80  ..O.1..k....
000009c: bf 03 4f f4 31 01 9f 6b e3 00 f7 00  ..O.1..k....
```

Comment: Foi de grande ajuda, obrigado.